# php string contains html number to special characters code

Tags: php

I'm currently working on kruti dev 010 font
my string contains *html number* like

```
& #39; ,& amp;,& quot;
```

I want to convert this word to **' & "**

```
<?php 
$string="my string with &#39;";
echo html_entity_decode($string); //not working
?>
```

I want output like

```
my string with '
```

Comment: &#39 to ' how to convert within a string

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars_decode("my string with &#39;",ENT_QUOTES);` emphasis on the `ENT_QUOTES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes are always a quick snag when you first try this with them. The trick is to add ENT_QUOTES to the function. See [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

```
<?php 
    $string="my string with &#39";
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode( "my string with &#39;" , ENT_QUOTES );
?>
```

Note: The semi-colon at the end of the character being decoded is not necessary, but is overall considered good posture. It is left out from above to better match the OPs -original- code.

Comment: Interestingly I found that it does not make a difference whether you add the `ENT_QUOTES` option to the parameter list or not. My [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qhrb-n50n) returns the same result in both cases. Hint: look at the page source and you will also see, that the ampersand is still encoded as `&amp;` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the beginning of your PHP script or adding `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'; Already enabled  in codeigniter framwork

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
$string="my string with &#39";
echo html_entity_decode($string); //not working
?>
```

You forgot the semicolon

```
$string="my string with &#39;";
```

Comment: please, try your answer before you post it.

Comment: Even though it doesn't work, he is right that OP forgot the semicolon

Comment: Not at a computer. Hard to test when on a mobile. But thanks for the tip, I usually test first anyhow.